# How to access async methods from WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-8, windows-store-apps, async-await

This is my WCF service with method `signIn()` which looks through a database for a user and returns it's `UserID`.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{


    [OperationContract]
    int signIn(string username, string password);
}
```

And derived class Service1

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
public int signIn(string username, string password)
    {
        GetHiredDBContext db = new GetHiredDBContext();

        foreach (User user in db.Users)
        {
            if(user.Username==username)
                if (user.Password == password)
                {
                    return user.UserID;
                }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

When I set this WCF service as a Service Reference in my Windows 8 Store App and access this method - `signIn()`, it says that this method is `async`.

My question is how to write the return value from the method to a variable and use it in client side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're working with Windows Store apps, then you want to become familiar with asynchronous programming, and the [`await`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh156528.aspx) keyword. It's not specific to WCF.

Use

```
var userId = await serviceClient.signIn(userName, password);
```

Comment: Does my method signIn() has to return type Task<int> instead of just int?

Comment: No. It should just return int.

Comment: Error: the await operator can only be used within an async method

Comment: Ok, so your calling method needs to be `async`: `private async bool IsValidUser(username, password)` or something. Really, read the article I linked to on `await`. My understanding is that most of the things you do in a Windows Store app will be async.

Comment: You should add an answer with your solution. You can get upvotes from that.

Comment: @JohnSaunders You can't make `async bool`o method, if you want an `async` method that returns a `bool`, it has to be `async Task<bool>`.

Comment: @svick it's a WCF service operation

Comment: @JohnSaunders That doesn't change the fact that you can't make an `async bool` method.

Comment: @svick: that's true, yet irrelevant. The non-async bool service operation will trigger an async bool proxy method to be created when the OP uses "Add Service Reference".